# can i solve the complex equation of a circle with center z1 and radius c, |z-z1| =c with z=re^{iθ} (the exponential form) ? how?

Tags: complex-numbers

1.
Can i solve the complex equation of a circle with center z1 and radius c, |z-z1| =c with z=re{iθ}(the exponential form) ? how?
how can i solve this equation for an arbitrary circle  |re{iθ}-z1| =c, with z1=r1e^{iθ1}(the center of the circle) and c the radius?
2.
And for the intersections of two circles how do i get a formula in terms of centers and radius with complex numbers?
i tried with analytic geometry to find a formula for the intersections of tow circles but it is impossible it is very very large solve x and y of (x−a)^{2}+(y−b)^{2}=r^{2},(x−c)^{2}+(y−d)^{2}=s^{2} for two arbitrary circles. i tried with vectors, and analytic geometry in polar coordinates, but i cant do it. it is impossible to get a formula in that areas. help me please!!!!

Comment: Please use Mathjax to make the question more readable

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a point of intersection of the two circles then

$$\frac{r_1{}^2}{a-z_1}-\frac{r_2{}^2}{a-z_2}+\overline{z_1}-\overline{z_2}=0$$

This follows from the fact that the equation of a circle (center:$z$, radius:$r$) is given by

$$\left|a-z|^2=(a-z)\left(\bar{a}-\bar{z}\right)\right.=r^2$$